# Select SQL with spaces in value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a php file like this:

```
<?php define('AREA', 'C');
    require ('prepare.php');
    require ('init.php');
    $con = mysql_connect(Registry::get ( 'config.db_host' ), Registry::get ( 'config.db_user' ), Registry::get ( 'config.db_password' ))or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    mysql_select_db(Registry::get ( 'config.db_name' ));
     if (!empty($_POST['dealer_company']))
     {
         $dealerCompany = 'Your company'; //$_POST['dealer_company'];                
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT distinct a.firstname, a.lastname, a.email, a.user_id
     FROM cscart_users a,cscart_usergroup_links b, cscart_usergroup_descriptions c
     WHERE b.usergroup_id=c.usergroup_id and b.status = 'A' and a.user_id=b.user_id and   
         c.usergroup='Dealer' and a.company = 'Your company'",$con) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $d_Infos[]=$row;            
        }
     }
     if (!empty($_POST['dealer_company']))
     {
        $dealerInfos = '<select id="as_dealer_id" name="as_dealer_id" class="input-text">
            <option value="">Please select</option>';

                        foreach ($d_Infos as $k => $v)
                        {
              $dealerInfos .= '<option value="'.$v['user_id'].'">'.$v['firstname'].'</option>';                
            } 
     $dealerInfos .= '</select>';
         echo $dealerInfos;
      }
?>
```

As you can see I have a condition is a.company = 'Your company' in the SQL query.
But it cannot select that column with that value. The result is empty. It will work if there's no spaces in "Your company", for example: "Yourcompany".
So my question is:
Is it possible to select a row with a condition contains spaces in it?
Thank you so much.

Comment: You can try with PHP's [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function which is one way of doing it. I'm sure there's an SQL equivalent, but I don't remember what it is. So try `$dealerCompany = trim('Your company ');` then with `and a.company = '".$dealerCompany."'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- your drunk.  is `a.company = 'Your company'` is fine, are you sure about the database value?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is my data in the dababase contain space too. In company column it is "Your company", too. :(

Comment: well i guess i dont get it, id the only space is between the 2 words then - ?

Comment: I don't know what is happening, either. The select statement work fine in phpmyadmin but can't select anything in php. I tried Like, too.
This is really wierd.

Comment: I suggest that you stop saving to DB, data that contains space(s) at beginning and/or the end. It's best to catch it "before" it enters in DB; now look what you're up against.

Comment: maybe if you dump a few rows from the db we will see the problem

Comment: I tried whole select statement in workbench and it not working, too.
But if I just using where a.company = "Your company" it worked. Is it because of too many conditions?

Comment: I tested a similar piece of code that I have kicking around here, and using `trim()` worked beautifully. It will remove any space(s) found to the left and/or right of a POST variable. I.e.: `$var=trim($_POST['var']);` <= so there's your answer.

Comment: hungbad you sure its not the php then

Comment: More specifically `$dealerCompany = trim($_POST['dealer_company']);` and custom-built just for you.

Comment: Sorry, I have taken a mistake in authorization variables. That's why it's not working.
Thank you so so much for you helps.

Comment: So, does `$dealerCompany = trim($_POST['dealer_company']);` work for you now? So I can make an answer and get all these lovely lovely points. lol

Comment: Ok, well it's up to you if you want me to put in an answer using my comment about using `$dealerCompany = trim($_POST['dealer_company']);` so we can close this question. Doesn't make any difference to me.

Comment: why are you using registry::get() in your code ?

Comment: @CodeLover this is one piece of controller in my client's framework, class registry is a storage for config data.

Comment: Try running a repair on your database. Obviously something is wrong there. Also check the collation and see if it is case sensitive or insensitive and make sure the database connection uses the same encoding. You probably are trying something else than 'YOUR COMPANY' so it might be good to see exactly what. Post your exact database schema and a dump of a few example rows that you actually used to query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following along with PHP's [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function.

```
$dealerCompany = trim($_POST['dealer_company']);
```

along with:

```
and a.company = '".$dealerCompany."'
```

this will "trim off" any space(s) to the left and/or right.

You can also use that same function when inserting data into DB. This will ensure that no spaces will be included at the left and/or right of the entry, should someone enter a space or spaces at the beginning and/or the end of the form's input element.

- It is best to do this right away in order to avoid complications.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, Added `a.company LIKE '%Your company%'`

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT distinct a.firstname, a.lastname, a.email, a.user_id
                               FROM cscart_users a,cscart_usergroup_links b, cscart_usergroup_descriptions c
                               WHERE b.usergroup_id=c.usergroup_id and b.status = 'A' and a.user_id=b.user_id and c.usergroup='Dealer' and a.company LIKE '%Your company%'",$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried, but won't work. This is really weird :(

Comment: mysql_query? nobody will tell him to use mysqli or pdo?

Answer (score 1):

You can add wildcard string (%) at the first and last of your data. but it also not search the string.

So two possibility is you trim all space to both side as

```
where replace(columnname ,' ','') = '''%'+ replace(@value,' ','') + '%'''

select REPLACE ('abadf adsfa',' ','')
```

or 
Second option is use FTS(Full text search).

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx